# Error message blocking TWebBrowser refreshes

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I'm using a TWebBrowser in my Delphi app. When an Internet Explorer Script Error dialog pops up it blocks automated refreshes (`"the requested resource is in use"`). Is there a way to automagically close the error dialog?
TIA
Steven

**edit**
One possible solution is to use the Mozilla ActiveX Control instead of IE's (Firefox never shows the error), but this has [its own problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668172/registering-mozctlx-dll-failed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the TWebBrowser Silent property to True in the Object Inspector or in code:

```
  WebBrowser1.Silent := True;
  WebBrowser1.Navigate2(sURl);
```

It will prevent the error dialog to pop up, so you don't have to close it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could close the dialog by clicking its button in code but probably a better way is to prevent the error that causes the dialog to display in the first place.

I'm only guessing here but I think you can get this error when you're trying to refresh the page before it's finished loading. The [`Navigate2`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser.Navigate2) method is asynchronous, ie. it returns immediately and the browser continues loading the page in a background thread. When the document is loaded the browser triggers the [`OnDocumentComplete`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser.OnDocumentComplete) event - which you should handle to update your state variable.
Don't try to call `Navigate2`, [`Refresh`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser.Refresh) or [`Refresh2`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser.Refresh2) before the current document has been loaded completely.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the `Navigate2`. I'll have to wait and see if this solves it, as I don't always get the error in the first place.

Comment: Doeas that mean you didn't use Navigate2 to load the document? What did you use?

Comment: I found a site where I get the error message each and every time (http://math.stackexchange.com). I get the error also with `Navigate2`. `OnDocumentComplete` isn't triggered until I close the error dialog.