# Registering mozctlx.dll failed

Tags: regsvr32

I'm trying to install Mozilla ActiveX Control v1.7.12. In the folder where the DLL resides I execute

```
regsvr32 mozctlx.dll
```

but this fails. I get an error message

```
DllRegisterServer in mozctlx.dll failed  
Return code was: 0x8002801c
```

I already tried an other version of the DLL, but no avail. Any ideas?
TIA
Steven

Answer (score 0):

Run command prompt as administrator, then execute the same command.

Comment: I am administrator on this machine, but thanks all the same for your answer.

Comment: On Vista, being logged on as an administrator is not enough. You need to run the command prompt elevated, right-click + "run as administrator".

Comment: I'm using XP (should have said it in my first comment, sorry)